# GCC pragma optimize does not override `-Og` command line setting

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

Is it possible to override the `-Og` GCC optimization level with `O2`/`O3` for a single function or compilation unit?

It seems that neither `#pragma GCC optimize("O2")` nor `__attribute__((optimize("O2"))` are obeyed by the compiler if `-Og` is used in the command line.

For example, [this function doing saturating addition](https://godbolt.org/z/Ngu5st) on ARM Cortex-M4. It gets compiled to `ssat` only if I compile with `-O2`, but the rightmost compiler uses `-Og` and ignores the pragma.

On the other hand, using a *lower* optimization level pragma works, i.e. specifying `O0` as pragma overrides `-Og` in command line.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to override the -Og GCC optimization level with O2/O3 for a single function or compilation unit?

Yes and no.  [The documentation for the `optimize` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes), to which the pragma's docs refer, says:

> The `optimize` attribute is used to specify that a function is to be compiled with different optimization options than specified on the command line.

So the attribute or pragma does override the command line.  That applies at the per-function level, however, whereas [the `-Og` option has both per-function and global effects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options):

> Like `-O0`, `-Og` completely disables a number of optimization passes so that individual options controlling them have no effect.

Thus, although using the attribute or pragma to set optimization level `O2` or `O3` does turn on all the individual optimizations that are included in that level, doing so may not have the full effect that setting them on the command line would do.

Note also the docs' caution that

> The `optimize` attribute should be used for debugging purposes only. It is not suitable in production code.

I take it that you *are* debugging, since that's the purpose of `-Og`, but among the things you should take from that comment is that you should not rely on that technique for forcing optimization options on or off.  As you have found, it might not do so effectively or fully.

> Is this expected behavior?

The behavior you describe seems consistent with the docs, though they do not specify the particulars.  The way you characterize it, however, as the pragma being ignored when `-Og` is set on the command line -- that is not expected, and I think not accurate.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfectly reasonable. The reason I asked the question is that in our company `-Og` is used for final, deployment builds. I don't find this to be a good practice, `Og` is considered a "good enough" optimization level for deployment (basically because `-O0` is a ridiculously slow reference level) and much easier to use for debugging compared to any higher levels. So I wanted to force optimization on all shared code which has been unit-tested and where I don't expect the need for debugging.